# coercing dataframes to matrices with multiple groups

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to know the equivalent of the following, but when I have more than one group of the same type of data.

Example A: to get my data into a pivoted matrix form, I can use the cast function i.e.

```
birthday_week   current_week    variable
26/03/2012  26/03/2012  100
26/03/2012  02/04/2012  125
02/04/2012  26/03/2012  50
02/04/2012  02/04/2012  10
```

This function :

```
as.matrix(cast(data,birthday_week ~current_week,value='variable'))
```

will give this result:

```
    26/03/2012  02/04/2012
26/03/2012  100 125
02/04/2012  50  10
```

However, my actual data has a few groups i.e.

```
    birthday_week   current_week    variable
group1  26/03/2012  26/03/2012  100
group1  26/03/2012  02/04/2012  125
group1  02/04/2012  26/03/2012  50
group1  02/04/2012  02/04/2012  10
group2  26/03/2012  26/03/2012  10
group2  26/03/2012  02/04/2012  15
group2  02/04/2012  26/03/2012  20
group2  02/04/2012  02/04/2012  10
```

What is the best way to get it into a list object with matrices inside it i.e.

```
$group1
        26/03/2012  02/04/2012
    26/03/2012  100 125
    02/04/2012  50  10

$group2 
        26/03/2012  02/04/2012
    26/03/2012  10  15
    02/04/2012  20  10
```

Comment: Can you post a `dput` of your data please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close:

```
library(reshape2)
lapply(split(df,df$group),
       function(df)acast(df,birthday_week~current_week,value.var="variable"))
# $group1
#            02/04/2012 26/03/2012
# 02/04/2012         10         50
# 26/03/2012        125        100
# 
# $group2
#            02/04/2012 26/03/2012
# 02/04/2012         10         20
# 26/03/2012         15         10
```

This assumes your data frame is named `df` and there is a column `group` with the grouping variable.

Comment: It looks good, however I wanted the birthday_week to be the row names, otherwise my objects are no longer matrices/ can't do matrix calculations on them

Comment: Use `acast(...)` instead of `dcast(...)`. See the edits above.